# Percentages in PHP

Tags: php, math, percentage

Not to sound stupid but I was wondering if there is a very simple way of taking a percentage from a number in PHP?

Say I have a number of 70.40 and I want to remove 15% of this.

So far I have something like:

```
$discount = 15;

$price = 70.40;

$newPrice = $price - (($discount / 100) * $price);
```

But this seems to be giving me all kinds of random numbers.

is there an easier way?

Comment: your code gives this new price, persistent. : 59.84. not okey ?

Comment: you wrote it wrong, as you wrote $newPrice is $price - 70.40% of $discount (70.40% of 15 = 10.56) but you want 15% of $price (the opposite), if you just change it with: $newPrice = $price - (($price / 100) * $discount); your code will be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function apply_discount($price, $discount) {
    $after_discount = $price - (($price / 100) * $discount);
    return $after_discount;
}
```

e.g.

```
echo apply_discount(200, 15); //170
```

Comment: should that work in this instance... "      $price = $row2["rrp"];
.....
$price = apply_discount($price,$_SESSION['discount']);" ..... With $price being brought from the database and the discount being stores in a session

Comment: @Kevlar variables are variables :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$discount = 15;
$price = 70.40;
$newPrice = $price * (100 - $discount) / 100;
```

If your `$discount` would be a percentage (between 0 and 1) it would be:

```
$discount = 0.15;
$price = 70.40;
$newPrice = $price * (1 - $discount);
```

Answer (score 0):

70.40 * 0.15 = 10.56

whereas 0.15 is 15%

I guess you could do something like this.

```
$discount = 0.15;
$price = 70.40;
$newPrice = $price - ($price * $discount);
```